# Editing an answer doesn't display the 'edit queue is full' error on submission

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I am trying to edit an answer to one of my questions as it has grammar and spelling mistakes. But when I click "Save edits" nothing happens.

Viewing the network requests displays the below URL with the message `The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!` but no snack bar or feedback is shown on the screen.

Is this just an issue for me or is this a bug?

`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66488852/edit-submit/164eb742-2075-4c98-87e8-e0eb7ff5c011`

[image]

Comment: This has happened to me recently too! Chrome on Windows 10, but I doubt it's a client-side problem.