# Why can I not edit this question?

Tags: support, edits, specific-edit

I was trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66518371/10352740) (to add the [sourcegenerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sourcegenerators) tag) but for some reasons, when I click the `Save edits` button nothing happens.

The suggested edit queue doesn't seem to be full, there's no error message appearing. All I have is the message indacting that a [recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28449850) has been declined and I should "review the reasons given for rejecting it", which I did.

How come I can't edit that question?

Comment: I didn't try to edit the tags, but I was able to edit the body without problems.

Comment: Tried again, it now works... Wonder if your edit changed something for me?

Comment: There are (currently) 481 suggested edits in the queue to be reviewed. I suspect there were 500 at the time - and that that's the hard limit.

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405776/editing-an-answer-doesnt-display-the-edit-queue-is-full-error-on-submission  it is a bug.

Comment: This happened to me, too. For me, when I made some body edits, I was able to save it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing an answer doesn't display the 'edit queue is full' error on submission](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405776/editing-an-answer-doesnt-display-the-edit-queue-is-full-error-on-submission)